# How can you get attribute names from an Entity from CoreData at an iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am reading data with following code from CoreData but instead of that can we read first attribute names  **"firstName", "lastName", "age"** from CoreData into an array and read their values instead of writing all the names in code.

It is repeated work because they are written in DataModel as well.

```
 loadData()  {
    
   let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Entity")
 
    
        do {
            let result = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
            dump(result)
            for data in result as! [NSManagedObject] {
                
                fNames = data.value(forKey: "firstName") as! String
                lNames = data.value(forKey: "lastName") as! String
                age = data.value(forKey: "age") as! Int
                
                print("first \(fNames),  last : \(lNames),  last : \(age)")
            }
        } catch {

        print("Could not load data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you have a custom `NSManagedObject` with a `firstName`, `lastName` and `age` property? That would avoid you `.value(forKey: "xxx") as! ZzZ`? So ` NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Entity")` would become ` NSFetchRequest<YourCoreDataModel>(entityName: "Entity")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the class that Xcode has generated for you that has the same name as the entity name

```
loadData()  {    
    //Declare fetch request to hold the class you want to fetch
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Entity>(entityName: "Entity")

    do {
        let result = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        dump(result)
        for data in result {     
            // result is now [Entity] so you can access properties directly
           //  and without casting           
            let firstName = data.firstName
            let lastName = data.lastName
            let age = data.age
            
            print("first \(firstName),  last : \(lastName),  age : \(age)")
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not load data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but you might want to change `print("Could not load data: \(error.localizedDescription)")` into `print("Could not load data: \(error)")` to avoid populating that often beginner misuse of printing `error` without interesting information.

Comment: @Larme, thanks for noticing this copy/paste error but actually for Core Data errors I find it best to cast to NSError and use localizedDescription

Answer (score 0):

Try this, access your entity name from `NSManagedObject`

**e.g.**

- For **AppDelegate.SharedInstance()**, just declare this func in AppDelegate.swift

```
class func sharedInstance() -> AppDelegate
{
        return UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
}
```

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName:"CallHistory") //Here CallHistory is my entity name which i can access as NSManagedObject
  
let arr_callhistory = try AppDelegate.sharedInstance().persistentContainer.viewContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [CallHistory]

 if arr_callhistory.count != 0
   {
      for callhistory_dict in arr_callhistory
      {
           let callStatus = callhistory_dict.callStatus
      }
 }
```

Comment: **Type 'AppDelegate' has no member 'sharedInstance'**

Comment: @Hope see updated answer